# asp.net Web Form custom error messages for each element

Tags: c#, webforms

I have created a web application - form, along with backend SQL insertions and queries.

Currently I am displaying all user error messages:-

```
    <div style="padding: 1em;">
                <asp:DataList ID="dtlERA_Errors" runat="server" Visible="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        -
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
   </div>
```

this div is at the bottom of my aspx page and it lists all errors in order.

However my goal is to create custom error messages for each element, displayed next to the elements (say a textbox) with a * and then the custom error message. I have seen a lot of modern web forms apply this technique.

Is this ajax/jquery based.... Can anyone provide me with some literature or a name (library) that I should look into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up on asp.net validation controls

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx

Comment: Well, to help you along :)  The validator call out is built on the asp.net validation controls.  So if you go with his second option, you should still read the page I posted.  Also, any jQuery validation will only be client side, while the asp.net validators are both client and server side.  Which is best practice.

Comment: yeah, I understand. I am reading both. and both of them are so cool! very exciting and refreshing.

Comment: Well, now I feel like a jerk :).  Although, I also highly recommend reading up on all the ajax toolkit extensions. (What Philo Posted)  They are updated regularly, and are worth getting to know.

Comment: I was trying to validate a particular user entry - must be 9 digits.

RangeValidation - minvalue: 100000000 maxvalue:999999999.

Is there any other method to validate the 9 digit entry using asp.net validation server controls?

Comment: Off the top of my head, you might be able to use the regex validator control.  Maybe this link can help with the expression itself. http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Comment: <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="* Must be 9 digits!" 
        ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{9}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

Comment: @Javalsu: 

I have a dateTime string and I m validating it using RegularExpression @ the client side and that works good.

On the server side I m validating if the user is actually inputting something in the string or leaving it empty, if empty then show error message.

However I was wondering if I could do both functionalities on the client side, required and then the regular expression, in a single statement?

Answer (score 2):

For jQuery, I recommend the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

For ASP.NET AJAX, I recommend the [ValidatorCallout](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ValidatorCallout/ValidatorCallout.aspx).